# troubles reading other apps config files

Tags: java, android, file

I have a problem. I have to access to the data folder of
other applications from my application
to read configuration's file and so on but it seems it's possible only
to read data from the sdcard and my application's data folder.
Can you suggest me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, it's a feature.

It would be a security risk if all applications had access to other apps data.